# Is there a limit for ft.search 'OR' query?

Tags: redis, redisearch

Is there a limit for number of search terms for ft.search 'OR' query for a TAG field?

Example: *ft.search my_index "@my_field:{item1 | item2 ...}"*

How far can I go? Can I have tens of thousands of search terms for a query?

Answer (score 2):

The only limitation is the number of bytes in redis command which is, IIRC, 512MB. Notice that it will come with performance penalty, having tens of thousands of search terms within OR query will significantly hart the performance (unless there is a very small number of results in each term ...)